# What is the common bugzilla hook for GIT?

Tags: git, githooks

I am looking for to find a git hook which submits posts to bugzilla when comit message includes fix/comment tags. However, I couldn't find a common tool. Here is a [list of alternatives on the Git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#Bug.2Fissue_trackers.2C_etc.). Does anyone know which tools are being used by Fedora or KDE?

Comment: Scmbug (mentioned on the list you linked to) can do that, sort of - unfortunately, its Git capabilities seem to have been written by a CVS/SVN person. It uses commit hooks to submit to the issue tracker, when it should probably be post-receive. That is, it detects the commits when they're made in a local repository, rather than when they're pushed to the central one. This is problematic for pretty obvious reasons, I think. (Git-bugzilla is mentioned there too, as sky100 points out.)

Comment: Oops, my bad, the list mentions git-bugzilla and git-bz, but not gitzilla.

Comment: scmbug seems so complex. As I mentioned below I tested gitzilla it just worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, the reason I posted that as a comment is that it was kind of an anti-answer. A previous workplace of mine used it, and it's on that list, but I don't much care for it, so I wanted to record that here as a caution to others looking for the same thing.

Comment: @Jefromi: In the first place gitzilla seemed so simple because of its size comparising with other tools such as scmbug. However, it does its job pretty good. Thanks again for your interest. I am using [this fork of the gitzilla](https://github.com/mehmed/gitzilla) and can write BUG:FIXED:123.

Comment: @Chris: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear - I meant that I was posting the note about scmbug as an anti-answer, i.e. a recommendation to use something else. Glad you found something better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which tools are used by Fedora or KDE but [this one](http://www.theoldmonk.net/gitzilla/) can be used as a hook for intergration of bugzilla and GIT. Hope it can help you.

Comment: I just packed pybugz and gitzilla and tested it. it worked, thanks. However, I just can write BUG123 to submit an entry to that bug. What if I also want change the status of the bug? For example, BUG123:FIXED.

Comment: If we want to change status of the bugzilla entry we can try [this fork of the gitzilla](https://github.com/mehmed/gitzilla). BUG:FIXED:ID, BUG:COMMENT:ID, BUG:CLOSED:ID options are available.